# Android: adb.exe problems with calling #

Tags: android, adb, urlencode, phone-call

I try to call `*100#` with the adb.exe program. I type the following in the command line:

```
adb.exe shell service call phone 2 s16 "*100#"
```

...but the telephone calls number `*100`, without **#** in the end, but I surely need it. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to URL encode your phone number. So try this:

```
adb.exe shell service call phone 2 s16 "*100%23"
```